# If $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ is finite, find $\lim_{x\to\infty} xf'(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

> If $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists and is finite, and $\lim_{x\to\infty} xf'(x)$ exists then find this limit

Intuitively I think $f'(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $ x \rightarrow \infty$ from first condition but that gives us a limit of $0·\infty$ form which can give us anything.

As $\ln(x)$ does not have a finite limit at infinity, and it's derivative is $\frac{1}{x}$, I suspect a function that does have a finite limit at infinity will have a derivative that decreases even faster such that $\frac{x}{\frac{1}{f'(x)}}$ will go to $0$ as $ x \rightarrow \infty$

Am I correct? If so, how can I formalize this as a proof?

Comment: See https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%20xf%27(x)%24&p=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\lim_{x \to \infty} xf'(x)=c>0$. Then there exists $x_0$ such that $f(x)-f(x_0)=\int_{x_0}^{x} f'(t)dt>\int_{x_0}^{x} \frac c {2t}dt=\frac  c  2[\ln x -\ln x_0]$ for all $x >x_0$.  But this contradicts the hypothesis (since $\ln x -\ln x_0 \to \infty$). [Clearly, $\lim_{x \to \infty} xf'(x)=\infty$ also leads to a  contradiction].  Similarly, $\lim_{x \to \infty} xf'(x)<0$ leads to a  contradiction, so the limit must  be $0$.